# Not able to save increment values in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to save value `id` as well when saving the data. I can do that with auto increment option but some reason I don't want to use that into the database.

Even, I am able to save the first record but after that it does repeat the previous id. Please help me to fix this issues. Many thanks

**Controller**

```
public function ajax_add()
{
    $this->_validate();
    $data = array(
        'VillageName'=> $this->input->post('VillageName'),
        'VillageCode'=> $this->input->post('VillageCode'),                              
        'VillageId_save'=> $this->input->post('VillageId_save'),                                
        'VillageType'=> $this->input->post('VillageType'),
        'BlockId'=> $this->input->post('BlockId'),
        'CreatedBy' => $this->input->post('CreatedBy'),
    );
    $insert = $this->village->save($data);
    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
}

public function get_lastvillageid()
{
    $data = $this->village->getLastInserted();
     echo json_encode($data[0]['VillageId']);
}
```

**View**

```
function save_vid()
{
  var id = $('#VillageId_save').val();
     $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            dataType:'json',
            url:'Village/get_lastvillageid',
            data:{'id':id},
            success:function(response){    
                console.log("Data is : "+response);
            console.log("Data is : "+ JSON.stringify(response));
               data = JSON.parse(response);
                $("#VillageId_save").val(data);
            }
    });
}

<input type="hidden" value="<?php
    foreach ($getLastInserted as $row) {              
        echo $row['VillageId']+1;
    }?>" name="VillageId_save" id ="VillageId_save"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

With PHP,

> Get last inserted id using mysql and increment by "1" then insert it. If no record set default "1".

For e.g.

```
/* Set DB Connection. */
$select_last_id = "select max(id) as auto_inc from table name";
$res = mysqli_query($mysqli,$select_last_id);
if(mysqli_num_rows($res)>0){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
    $new_increment_id = intval($row['auto_inc'])+1;
}
else{
    $new_increment_id = 1;
}
```

Comment: I wanted to do this through ajax. otherwise it will create a duplicate id.